# Is there any way of disabling function folding on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode with the `Vim` plugin just so I'm able to use vim keybindings inside VSCode. I also use the [Explicit folding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding) extension to choose folding markers of my choice on the code. Everything works fine except that the function folding is not disabled when I activate the marker folding with the Explicit folding extension.

The problem starts when I try to use these two Vim keybindings:

```
zM- closes all foldings recursively
zR- opens all foldings recursively
```

Since the function folding is not deactivated, it doesn't matter how I organize my foldings with markers, `zM` will close all functions together with my markers and that will make a mess with the code. I'd like to find a way of deactivating the function folding on VSCode and leaving only the marker folding... On the settings I found the following option:

[image]

But this option disables all foldings (functions and markers)... Is there any way of disabling only the function foldings?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the extension you linked says this in the documentation:

**Auto Fold**

You can define the automatic folding of the ranges with the property explicitFolding.autoFold (an enum, none by default).
Each rule can overwrite that property with its own property autoFold (a boolean, false by default).

So you can auto fold only the imports with:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "explicitFolding.rules": [
        {
            "beginRegex": "^import\\b",
            "whileRegex": "^(?:import\\b|\\/\\/)",
            "autoFold": true
        }
    ],
    "explicitFolding.autoFold": "none"
}
```

Could you use that functionality and put your desired markers in the `explicitFolding.rules` array?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the `autoFold` is meant for... But it doesn't solve the problem of my original question... I've actually opened an issue on the [Explicit folding GitHub page](https://github.com/zokugun/vscode-explicit-folding/issues/94) and the developer of the extension confirmed it is a real issue with VSCode. At the time now (October 2022) there's not much to do besides installing a different branch of VSCode where the feature of disabling function folding individually is implemented.